# SQL vs jQuery String Length Issue

Tags: jquery, sql, string

I am trying to find length of a string using Sql Server (LEN) and jQuery ($(this).val().length). Both are returning different length values. String content is given below.

*'Project Noida Ka-Rate Gr. Noida Ka

AJNARA AMBROSIA-Sec. 118

Bigsize 2BHK Rs 38.27*Lac onwrds

3BHK Rs 51.55*Lac onwrds

Spanish Theme

Bang on FNG

 xxxxxxxxxx'*

SQl Server returns 161 characters while jQuery 155. Can somebody please pin-point what I am missing here.

Comment: sql/serverside language might encode some of the characters so you may have more in the db

Comment: @madalinivascu any idea how to disable the encoding while calculating length at sql server level? Thank you for your response.

Comment: its a bad idea to disable it, what happens if the db doesn't support that character?

Comment: @madalinivascu you were right. It was new line that was causing issue. I simply replaced it with a blank character to have actual length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be it is because of the character encoding used on your sql server database. As I am testing it on mysql it is showing 156 length.

Comment: May be. Any idea how to check or disable that?

Comment: Its a bad idea to disable it. Instead you can calculate length in your server side scripting language i.e. ASP, I think it will give you the correct length.

Comment: you were right. It was new line character (CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)) encoding that was causing issue. I simply replaced it with a blank character to have actual length.